# e.preventDefault not preventing submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

So on localhost I have no issues with the function at all, it works flawless but now I uploaded it to my host and it doesn't seem to work anymore. The form gets somewhat submitted and the URL gets all the info from the datastring in it. Please help me fix it.

This gets added to the URL in the addressbar:

> ?inlineRadioOptions=pre-set&customname=&customtype=&Crime=&DescriptionForm=&inlineRadioOptions3=none&Report=&selected-text=1&CordX=4675&CordY=4558&SubmitCrime=

```js
$("#CrimeForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#RadioCrime2').is(':checked')) {
    var Crime = $("#customname").val();
    var Type = $("#customtype").val();
  } else {
    var Crime = $("#select2").val();
    var Type = 'NONE';
  }

  if ($('#RadioDiv2').is(':checked')) {
    var UseDiv = 1;
  } else {
    var UseDiv = 0;
  }

  var value = $(this).find('select[name="DivisionSelect"]').val();
  var divss = (value ? value.join('') : '');

  var DescriptionForm = $("#DescriptionForm").val();
  var Report = $("#Report").val();
  var PinID = $("#selected-text").val();
  var CordX = $("#CordXNew").val();
  var CordY = $("#CordYNew").val();
  var UserID = <?php echo $AccountID;?>;
  var dataString = 'Crime=' + Crime + '&Type=' + Type + '&DescriptionForm=' + DescriptionForm + '&PinID=' + PinID + '&CordX=' + CordX + '&CordY=' + CordY + '&UserID=' + UserID + '&DivSelect=' + UseDiv + '&Divs=' + divss + '&Report=' + Report;
  if (Crime == '' || Type == '' || DescriptionForm == '' || PinID == '' || CordX == '' || CordY == '') {
    document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">You need to fill out everything!</div>';
  } else {
    var n = DescriptionForm.length;
    if (n > 500) {
      document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">You have ' + n + ' characters in the description, limit them to 500!</div>';
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SendInput.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">' + result + '</div>';
          $('#DescriptionForm').val('');
          $('#customname').val('');
          $('#Report').val('');
          $('#customtype').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
          $("#select2").val(null).trigger("change");
          document.getElementById("CustomCrime").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("DefaultCrime").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("RadioCrime").checked = true;
          document.getElementById("RadioDiv").checked = true;
          document.getElementById("ChooseDivision").style.display = "none";
          $("#DivisionSelect option:selected").prop("selected", false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Need to see your code...

Comment: Gimme a sec, for some reason it didnt add it to the post

Comment: Put your code here, unless it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: Probably the issue is in the cache. Try clear your browser cache to remove any cached scripts.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3yAG6ZNP is the code, sorry, for some reason errors occur when i try to paste it in the editor.....

Comment: is your request going to a different domain?

Comment: @andreim nope, it's going to "SendInput.php" which is in the same folder as the index.php

Comment: Does this function get called at all? Does your `form` element have the id `CrimeForm`?

Comment: Are you including the JavaScript before the content of the page?

If so, you'll need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function () {...})`.

Comment: The javascript is inside the index.php file, and the form does have that id yes. It works fine on localhost just not on the host.

Comment: php is serverside.  All php does is *generate* an HTML page. You still need to wrap your JS in a document.ready call or it will run before the rest of the HTML content is downloaded and be unable to find your elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on form submission and its event cancellation, you can use a regular button within your form.
The button being sort of like:`<input type='button' id='btnSendCrimeForm' value='Send Form' />`

Then, within the contents of a document.ready callback, you can register to the aforementioned button's `click` event, within which you execute the code you wanted to execute upon form submission.

```
$("#btnSendCrimeForm").click(function(e) {
    if($('#RadioCrime2').is(':checked')) {
        var Crime = $("#customname").val();
        var Type = $("#customtype").val();
    }else{
        var Crime = $("#select2").val();
        var Type = 'NONE';
    }

    if($('#RadioDiv2').is(':checked')) {
        var UseDiv = 1;
    }else{
        var UseDiv = 0;
    }

    var value = $(this).find('select[name="DivisionSelect"]').val();
    var divss = (value ? value.join('') : '');

    var DescriptionForm = $("#DescriptionForm").val();
    var Report = $("#Report").val();
    var PinID = $("#selected-text").val();
    var CordX = $("#CordXNew").val();
    var CordY = $("#CordYNew").val();
    var UserID = <?php echo $AccountID;?>;
    var dataString = 'Crime='+ Crime + '&Type='+ Type + '&DescriptionForm='+ DescriptionForm +'&PinID='+ PinID + '&CordX='+ CordX + '&CordY='+ CordY + '&UserID='+ UserID + '&DivSelect='+ UseDiv + '&Divs='+ divss + '&Report='+ Report;
    if(Crime==''||Type==''||DescriptionForm==''||PinID==''||CordX==''||CordY=='')
    {
        document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">You need to fill out everything!</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        var n = DescriptionForm.length;
        if(n > 500){
            document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">You have '+ n +' characters in the description, limit them to 500!</div>';
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SendInput.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    document.getElementById("Alert-group").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'+result+'</div>';
                    $('#DescriptionForm').val('');
                    $('#customname').val('');
                    $('#Report').val('');
                    $('#customtype').prop('selectedIndex',0);
                    $("#select2").val(null).trigger("change"); 
                    document.getElementById("CustomCrime").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("DefaultCrime").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("RadioCrime").checked = true;
                    document.getElementById("RadioDiv").checked = true;
                    document.getElementById("ChooseDivision").style.display = "none";
                    $("#DivisionSelect option:selected").prop("selected", false);
                }   
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```